# Where should I put the const keyword?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

Take a look at the following source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef _PATIENT_H_
#define _PATIENT_H_

#include "Base.cpp"

class Patient: public Base
{
private:
    std::string name_;
    std::string date_of_birth_;
    std::string sex_;
public:
    void set_name(std::string & name)
    {
        name_ = name;
    }
    std::string get_name() const
    {
        return name_;
    }
    void set_date_of_birth(std::string & date_of_birth)
    {
        date_of_birth_ = date_of_birth;
    }
    std::string get_date_of_birth() const
    {
        return date_of_birth_;
    }
    void set_sex(std::string & sex)
    {
        sex_ = sex;
    }
    std::string get_sex() const
    {
        return sex_;
    }
};
#endif
```

I have two questions here:

1. Should `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>` be inside `#define _PATIENT_H_`?
2. In the setter accessors, how should I write the `const` keyword:
   a. `void set_name(const std::string & name)`
   b. `void set_name(std::string const & name)`

?

Comment: 1: Yes, 2: Whichever you like more.

Comment: Fyi, `#include "Base.cpp"` - preprocess -including *anything* .cpp is a code smell. There should be a `Base.h` there, and proper build steps to build `Base.cpp` and whatever else you're building.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Most developers that I work with are *Const West* (the const appears first), but there is a smaller cadre of developers that I work with that prefer *East Const* (the const is after the type).  In the code given, it doesn't matter to the compiler.  Whichever you find more readable.

Comment: Nothing in the patient class uses anything from iostream. Don't include what you don't use. And that inclusion of `Base.cpp` looks suspect to any C++ savvy programmer.

Comment: Also please read [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) Any and all symbols beginning with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_PATIENT_H_`) are reserved everywhere.

Comment: @Eljay - "*most*", *"smaller"*... citation required.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica • I updated my comment to reflect the source of my qualifiers.  I'm in the *East Const* camp.

Comment: [NL.26](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rl-const) says `const` first is "far more common, conventional".  I couldn't find a poll of *Const West* versus *East Const* preferences.  (Apparently the Tabs-v-Spaces and Where-the-Curly-Braces-Go holy wars weren't enough.)

Comment: @Eljay IIRC, the point is that east const is allegedly more consistent. E.g. `int *const` (right-to-left "const pointer to int") is similar to `int const` (right-to-left "const int").

Comment: @HolyBlackCat • Yes, that's the rationale us *East Const-ers* use to advocate & evangelize it.  It's more const-sistent (*ba-dum-tiss*).

Answer (score 2):

1. It doesn't matter, but I would prefer the include guard as the first thing in the file. The reasons are:

   - The preprocessor has to do less things when you include the file more than once.
   - The preprocessor can recognize this as a classical include guard, and handle it in an optimized manner.
   - It's more common, and it's easier to notice if you have a lot of `#include`s.
2. It doesn't matter. `const std::string` is more traditional, but some people use `std::string const` claiming it to be easier to read.

And an obligatory reminder that including `.cpp` files is not recommended.